# Apagando arquivos de um diretório em PHP

Tags: php, arquivo

Tenho um diretório com imagens e preciso que cada vez que inicia o programa as imagens sejam excluídas exceto uma.

Tenho por enquanto o seguinte código:

```
    $dirtmp = "fotos/tmp";
    $ditmp = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirtmp, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $ritmp = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ditmp, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

    foreach ( $ritmp as $file ) {
           unlink($file);
    }
```

Isso faz com que apague todos os arquivos, porém gostaria que o arquivo `zVazio.jpg` nunca fosse apagado dessa pasta.

Existe alguma forma de antes de excluir (`unlink`) fazer a verificação do nome do arquivo e caso seja `zVazio.jpg` ele não exclua ?

Answer (score 1):

Pode garantir que o nome sempre será assim? Se for isso basta filtrar quando encontrar o nome esperado no arquivo sendo considerado. Se não puder garantir isso pode precisa fazer alguma outra operação como normalizar tudo para minúsculo.

Isso não lida com certos problema, como falta de permissão.

Tem outras formas de pegar o nome, mas achei que essa atende bem. Só cuidado porque verificar se o nome é só isso ou se ele está em qualquer parte pode dar falso positivo.

```
$dirtmp = "fotos/tmp";
$ditmp = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirtmp, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ritmp = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ditmp, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($ritmp as $file) if (!endsWith($file, "zVazio.jpg")) unlink($file);

function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);
    if ($length == 0) return true;
    return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
```

Se preferir pode fazer:

```
$dirtmp = "fotos/tmp";
$ditmp = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirtmp, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ritmp = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ditmp, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($ritmp as $file) if ($file->getFilename() != "zVazio.jpg") unlink($file);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/Filter.php).

Comment: perfeito... o nome do arquivo sera sempre o mesmo....

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se o `$file` ta vindo corretamente com o nome do arquivo e faz um `if`:

```
if ('zVazio.jpg' === $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

Se não tiver certeza do nome/caminho do arquivo, pode tentar usar o `strpos` pra verificar se o nome do arquivo consta na string `$file`:

```
if (strpos($file, 'zVazio.jpg') === false) {
    unlink($file);
}
```